# How to apply query operation only to first entity in Azure table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying my best to keep the query operation simple by just querying the first record of a table to check if my query is valid and throws no exception.

I have seen many answers on SO about retrieving top 'n' entities. My requirement here is, to apply query operation to only the first entity, no matter if that matches the filters specified in the query and abort.

I tried:

```
TableQuery query = new TableQuery().Where("MyKey eq 'RawMaterial'").Take(1);
```

But this query performs a complete table scan if there is no matching entity. Any comments on this?

Comment: If you are searching for one, you have to scan ALL if there is no matching.

Comment: That's where the question actually lies. The requirement is "Pick the first entity, fetch if it matches, else abort!"

Comment: Take in library will abort when number is reached and not search entire list.

Comment: can you write down an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code :

```
            List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000).Select(x => x).ToList();

            DateTime startAll = DateTime.Now;
            List<int> none = numbers.Where(x => x == -1).Take(1).ToList();
            DateTime endAll = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime startOne = DateTime.Now;
            List<int> one = numbers.Where(x => x == 1).Take(1).ToList();
            DateTime endOne = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("Time One : {0}, Time All {1}", endOne.Subtract(startOne).ToString(), endAll.Subtract(startAll).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is not about list. Its about fetching first entity alone from Azure table storage.

Comment: What the code does is compare the times going through the entire list verses only reading one value.  If you are using First(), there is always an Enumerable list. Your table is an Enumerable List.